# An exception occurred processing JSP page, line points to startsWith() method

Tags: java, jsp

I have the following code in my JSP:

```
String name=request.getParameter("name");

if(name.startsWith("315")){
        query="select pass from students where regno='"+name+"'";
        url1="marks.jsp";
    }
else{
        query="select pass from staff where name='"+name+"'";
        url1="staff.jsp";
    }
```

When I run this JSP, I get a HTTP 500 error page:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 35

32:         String url1="";
33:         if(name!="")
34:         {
35:         if(name.startsWith("315")){
36:             query="select pass from students where regno='"+name+"'";
37:             url1="marks.jsp";
38:         }


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

It says that "An exception" has occurred. You should look further down in the stacktrace or in the server logs for that exception. One of the exceptions which could occur on the particular line of code is a `NullPointerException`. This will happen when `name` is actually `null` (i.e. the parameter is *not* been sent along with the request). Your code is not checking for that beforehand at all. The following check in your code

```
if (name!="") {
    // ...
}
```

makes really no sense. It would always return `true`, expect when `name` refers actually exactly the same empty string instance `""` in the memory. If you want to check if it is not `null` and not empty, then you should instead be checking as follows:

```
if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

That said, you've a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) hole there in your code. You're not escaping the user-submitted value, but inlining it in the SQL query string. Anyone could easily submit (partial) SQL query strings as request parameter and be able to execute a completely different SQL query (like a `DROP`, `TRUNCATE`, etc). I recommend to take some time apart to [learn how to use `PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Last but not least, a JSP file is the wrong place to put Java code in. I'd also recommend to take some time apart to [learn how to use servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and links.